# How to use PDF file as data source in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, pdf, ssis, etl

I'm wondering it's possible using PDF how data source in SSIS. I've tried converting to another flat file, but I haven't been able to. Please is someone have a script to convert PDF or something that might help me.

Answer (score 2):

First, You have to specify if the .pdf file contains text, table or just images. If the pdf file can be parsed (not images / scanned documents), then you can use a Script Component as Source and write a C# code to convert the pdf content into rows.

You can refer to the following links for more details about parsing pdf and using Script Component as Source:

*Parsing pdf using C#*

- [Convert a pdf file to text in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944576/convert-a-pdf-file-to-text-in-c-sharp)
- [Converting PDF to Text in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12445/Converting-PDF-to-Text-in-C)
- [Read and Extract PDF Text in C# and VB.NET](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-read-pdf/305)

*Using Script Component as Source*

- [Creating a Source with the Script Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-data-flow-script-component-types/creating-a-source-with-the-script-component?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [SSIS – USING A SCRIPT COMPONENT AS A SOURCE](https://www.ssistalk.com/2007/04/04/ssis-using-a-script-component-as-a-source/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer: The pdf contain only text. I've been testing the script but some classes are not VS