# How can I convert a pdf to iTextSharp.Text.Image?

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf

I have a pdf file, and I need to convert it to iTextSharp image during running my VB.NET program.

I've searched for it, but couldn't find anything. Is it even possible?

Comment: "during runing my VB.NET program" Then why tag your question with C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Pdf file pages to Images with itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125117/convert-pdf-file-pages-to-images-with-itextsharp)

Comment: You don't need iTextSharp ; you can convert pdf to images with **Windows.Data.Pdf.PdfDocument** (tested in Winforms/VB.NET with _Windows.winmd_)